# Dynamic SQL Query based on pandas dataframe Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing the below issue.

I have a dataframe containing:  **ID, date, previous_date.**

I also have a table stored in an SQL Server database containing **ID, Date, Value** and I want to achieve the following:

Search each ID from dataframe at the db table and return the sum of a value occured between date and previous date at a new column named **desired_value**.

**Starting dataframe**

```
ID  Date    previous_date   desired_value
5   15/3/2020   15/1/2020   16
7   25/6/2019   19/5/2019   8
```

**DB Table**

```
ID  Date    Value
 5  13/1/2020   5
 5  16/1/2020   7
 5  17/2/2020   9
 7  21/5/2019   4
 7  17/6/2019   4
```

As fas as I can imagine, query must be executed in a loop, for each row of the starting dataframe.

I have in my mind something like this

```
my_query = "select ID, sum(Value) from db_table WHERE ID in {}".format(tuple(df['ID']))
```

but how can i pass the parameters of date inside?

or this

```
for index,row in left.iterrows():
x = cursor.execute('''
            SELECT [ID], SUM([Value]) FROM db.table
            WHERE Date > ? AND Date < ?
            GROUP BY ID
        ''',row['Date'],row['previous_date']
        )
```

But x will be then a cursor object...

**Note:** Pandas dataframe and the db table contain same ids multiple times with different dates (imagine it like orders per id).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from posting images of your expected results, images should only be used as a last resort when it can't be expressed through text. You will get more help this way. Second, stackoverflow is not a 'write my code'/outsourcing service. If you're getting stuck on something or don't understand a particular aspect, explain this. But show what you have tried, and then people can help you. See this link for more pointers: [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @DKramer. I removed the image and described the problem with text. Regarding solution  i don't have a clear image of what's the best way to achieve this, i just sense that i have to iterate through the dataframe for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to do a cumulative sum of the Value column from the database, based on conditions on from the dataframe. So, assuming you have read the database into a dataframe called *database_df*, and assuming you have a starting dataframe that does not include yet the desired value *starting_df*, you could do the followint

```
starting_df = starting_df.merge(database_df, on=["id"])
starting_df = starting_df.loc[(starting_df.date > starting_df.previous_date) 
                              & (starting_df.date <= starting_df.Date),:]
starting_df = starting_df.groupby(by=["id", "Date", "previous_date"]).sum()
```

Result frame will be a [DataFrameGroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) object as below. I let you look around on how to transform it into a DataFrame object if you need to.

```
                             value
id Date       previous_date       
5  2020-03-15 2020-01-15        16
7  2019-06-25 2019-05-19         8
```

You can find more information on [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) etc..

Comment: Thanks ! This works like a charm. I completely missed this kind of solution and was thinking more complex. I just added reset_index() in the end of the final command.

Answer (score 0):

The question originally had a sql tag.

If I understand the logic, you want a `join` and aggregation:

```
select s.date, s.date, s.previous_date, sum(db.value)
from starting s left join
     db
     on db.id = s.id and
        db.date between s.previous_date and s.date
group by s.date, s.date, s.previous_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon.
Here, i have to do with a pandas dataframe and a stored db table (which i can pass it as a dataframe). So as far as I can understand, you wrote the logic in an sql basis supposing the left table is stored in the database which is false because the left table (starting) is not a db table but a pandas dataframe. 
I also, forgot to mention that ID is  NOT unique at the left table (pandas dataframe). Thank you

Comment: @AntonisAgg . . . Your question is tagged SQL.  This is a SQL answer.

Comment: You are right, i fixed it. Thanks for your interest in my question Gordon.